# R Moving Window Model fit with variable window size

Tags: r, time-series, linear-regression, modeling

Currently, I am working with data frames in R, the first column of which is a numeric for date. I now have the data sorted in ascending order of date. I want to fit a model (the code I've provided is a simple OLS model) for a 20 day period but for now I've had to assume that I have exactly 124 observations per day, requiring me to use a for loop, however that is not the case. Is there a way for me to include a 20 day window without making that assumption? The current algorithm I have is below. Any help would be much appreciated. The inputs are a data set and two integers, predict and predictor.

```
rollerOLS <- function(data, predict, predictor){
  res <- list()
  alpha <- c()
  beta <- c()
  m <- dim(data)[1]
  for(i in 1:(floor(m/124)-10)){
    data.new <- as.data.frame(data[c((1+(124*(i-1))):((i+9)*124)),])
    data.pred <- as.data.frame(data[c((1+(124*(i+9))):((i+10)*124)-1),])
    n <- dim(data.new)[1]
    k <- dim(data.pred)[1]
    x <- data.new[-1,predictor]
    y <- data.new[-n, predict]
    mod <- lm(y ~ x)
    ts <- mod$coefficients[1] + mod$coefficients[2]*data.pred[-1,predictor] 
    actual <- data.pred[-k,predict]
    alpha[i] <- mod$coefficients[1]
    beta[i] <- mod$coefficients[2]
  }
  coef <- as.data.frame(cbind(alpha, beta))
  res$coefs <- coef
  res <- as.data.frame(res)
  return(res)
}
```

Comment: Please show `dput(data)` or its `dput(head(data))`

Comment: It's obviously a large data set so I only include the head of the data. 
structure(list(date = c(17169.1354166667, 17169.1423611111, 17169.1458333333, 
17169.1493055556, 17169.1527777778, 17169.15625), OPEN = c(14.07, 
13.92, 13.96, 13.97, 13.97, 13.98), HIGH = c(14.07, 13.97, 13.98, 
13.97, 13.99, 13.99), LOW = c(13.97, 13.92, 13.85, 13.97, 13.96, 
13.98), LAST_PRICE = c(13.99, 13.95, 13.97, 13.97, 13.98, 13.98
), TR = c(0.75, 1.5, 0.75, 1, 1, 1)), .Names = c("date", "OPEN", 
"HIGH", "LOW", "LAST_PRICE", "TR"), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")